# Drawing two semi-connected grids of circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to replicate the image below from neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com (chapter 6):

[image]

I got the grids (the 2nd isn't centered though) but I don't know how to add the lines/arrows and the captions above the grids.

My code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,...,27}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,27} {
        \ifthenelse{\x < 5 \AND \y > 22}{\draw[black] (0.2*\x, 0.2*\y) circle (0.05cm);}{\draw[gray] (0.2*\x, 0.2*\y) circle (0.05cm);}
    }

  \foreach \x in {0,...,23}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,23} {
        \ifthenelse{\x < 1 \AND \y > 22}{\draw[black] (8 + 0.2*\x, 0.2*\y) circle (0.05cm);}{\draw[gray] (8 + 0.2*\x, 0.2*\y) circle (0.05cm);}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `\node`s instead of `\draw` commands, then you can conveniently label each of the circles based on the values of `\x` and `\y`. You can then use those labels both to draw the lines and to place the captions:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0.5mm]
  \foreach \x in {0,...,27}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,27} {
        \ifthenelse{\x < 5 \AND \y > 22}
        {\node[circle,draw=black] (A-\x-\y) at (0.2*\x, 0.2*\y) {};}
        {\node[circle,draw=gray] (A-\x-\y) at (0.2*\x, 0.2*\y) {};}
    }

  \foreach \x in {0,...,23}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,23} {
        \ifthenelse{\x < 1 \AND \y > 22}
        {\node[circle,draw=black] (B-\x-\y) at (8 + 0.2*\x, 0.4 + 0.2*\y) {};}
        {\node[circle,draw=gray] (B-\x-\y) at (8 + 0.2*\x, 0.4 + 0.2*\y) {};}
    }
    \draw[->] (A-0-27) -- (B-0-23);
    \draw[->] (A-0-26) -- (B-0-23);
    \draw[->] (A-0-25) -- (B-0-23);
    \draw[->] (A-0-24) -- (B-0-23);
    \draw[->] (A-0-23) -- (B-0-23);
    \node[above=6pt] at (A-14-27) {input neurons};
    \node[above=6pt] at (B-11-23) {first hidden layer};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: grid of circles with lines]